# Do we ever see the Senshi de-transform?

Tags: sailor-moon

The *henshin* (or, transformation) sequences in *Bishoujo Senshi Sailor Moon* are legendary for being *awesome*, but do we ever see them change back into their civilian identities?

I'm requesting either video links, screencaptures, or panels from the manga for this one, because I'd like to see the scenes myself! Examples from *both* the anime and the manga would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can remember, there was no spontaneous de-transformation. All the de-transformations were non-stontaneous (i.e.; lose of power, falling unconscious, etc). If you count Tuxedo Kamen as a senshi, he shows one and only one spontaneous de-transformation in SMR. It has been a lot of time since I last watched the overall series, so I don't remember any episode numbers.

Comment: @hkBattousai I think your comment is better suited as an actual answer, even if you don't have the episode numbers. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In episode 45 of the dub, Sailor Moon is forcibly de-transformed at ~11:44. When it does, she "ribbons" back to her civilian clothes.

In episode 108 of the dub, we see Sailor Uranus de-transforms (at ~21:12), willingly, by going nude briefly before she appears in her civilian clothes.

In the manga. it looks like they use the transformation pen to [de-transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl0Zj.jpg) a la ribbons.

So it seems they typically get surrounded by ribbons again and revert back to their civilian clothes.

Comment: FWIW the latter occurrence (where Sailor Uranus de-transforms) corresponds to 115 of the sub.

Comment: The first two links are broken.

Answer (score 9):

What I've found:

- *Sailor Moon R the Movie: Promise of the Rose* - Sailor Moon is forcibly detransformed by Fiore, twice. Both times are during the later half on the movie, on the asteroid. The first one is the asteroid-flower scene with Sailor Moon tied-up in vines.
- *Sailor Moon SuperS* - I believe it's also in the later half on the movie, on the ship. The Inner and Outer senshi/soldiers have their power drained, having them detransformed. However, they only appear as their colored-barbie forms, likely because it showed them frontally "nude" for around 12 seconds. - [YouTube reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_s74tAFSKQ).

Answer (score 4):

In the anime, there was a scene or two where the senshi were forced to transform back by draining power or similar.

Actual detransformation was done by "ripping" the transformation off (though not as visible as in some other series), which'd suggest normal transformation would be something different, which I remember not be shown at any time.

Looks like there was (at least one) back-transformation in anime too.

Answer (score 1):

In episode 8 of Sailor Moon Crystal, Sailor Venus is shown intentionally de-transforming in front of the other senshi.

Answer (score 1):

In episode 8 of the third season of Sailor Moon Crystal (episode 34 of the entire adaptation), we see Sailor Chibi Moon revert back to her civilian costume after her brooch is stolen (along with her "copy" of the Legendary Silver Crystal and her soul) by a transformed Hotaru. (We learn in the next episode that Hotaru has transformed into Mistress 9.)

We can assume then that one of these objects—presumably the brooch and/or the soul, as the other Sailor Guardians do not have the Legendary Silver Crystal—is necessary for "maintaining" the transformed state. (It is of course obvious that the brooch is needed for the transformation, but it does not seem clear to me whether or not the Sailor Guardians could drop their brooches while transformed and stay transformed. Perhaps the distance from a Sailor Guardian and her brooch could also matter.)